# Strange behaviour of readline in Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, bufferedreader, readline, inputstreamreader

I got a very strange problem. I am trying to read the result of a command I am executing. The code never reaches the println-Statement. It is just "hanging up" the program, if the end of the output is reached. No failure and no exception.

My project is a mix of Scala and Java. So it doesn't matter in which language the solution is. I tried in both. The encoding of my project is Cp1252.

Here is my code

```
var fileScript = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PathOfScript)
var isr:InputStreamReader  = new InputStreamReader(fileScript.getInputStream())
var in = new BufferedReader(isr)
var line:String = ""
try {
  while ({line = in.readLine();  line!= null}) {
    println("line: "+line)
  }
  println("OUTSIDE !!!");
  in.close();
}
```

Comment: Does the script process actually complete? Are you sure it's giving output to stdout instead of stderr?

Comment: What does the PathOfScript var contain? Excatly?

Comment: The Path is "c:\\nusmv\\nusmv -source script.cmd". The whole output is reachable with the code...it is just "hanging up", if it reaches the end. So it think, that everything is in  stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange... my Java version works just fine:

```
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:\\anyfile"));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = "";
        try {
          while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("line: "+line);
          }
          System.out.println("OUTSIDE !!!");
          in.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I think that the problem is in fileScript: if it gives a stream and doesn't close it, you'll never get a null in the while loop. Check that part. Try with a regular file (like I did in my example). If it works, the problem is surely in the fileScript object.

Comment: Yes, thats right, but i cant use it. I can save the output to a file with an option in the script and read the file. Then everything is fine. The problem is, that it takes a while until the output is written to the file. And i am checking many scripts. Is there maybe a solution to check if the file is already written, without Threads? If i check with file.exists(), i get the feedback false. If i wait for a few milliseconds it seems to be ok. But if the code will be used on slower systems, than i can not be sure, that it works.

Comment: Can you try it with the following command (or, if you have linux, ls):
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir").getInputStream());

Comment: Yes that works. So the problem is the output of my script? I want to thank you in advance Igor, i appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, and yes, I think that the problem is in the script you are running. I guess, it's no longer a Java thread, so good luck in further investigation! :)

Comment: It was the script. Thank you!